# how can I check which submit button is clicked

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I use laravel framework of php ...

I have a form with 3 submit button that each of them do different task . but how can I find in my controller side that which one was clicked?
I define name for each of them but when I print_r($_POST) there is nothing about my buttons name . so how can I check which one was pressed?

```
    {{Form::submit('send',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'send'))}}
    {{Form::submit('cancel',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','data-dismiss'=>'modal','aria-    hidden'=>'true'])}}
    {{Form::submit('save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'save'))}}
```

thanks for time :)

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: You should give them all the same name (eg action), and a different **value**, then you can do a switch case /if statement on `$_POST['action']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you can set the same name, and a different value for each submit button, then check the value in the controller:

```
{{Form::submit('send',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'action','value'=>'send'))}}
{{Form::submit('cancel',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','data-dismiss'=>'modal','aria-    hidden'=>'true','name'=>'action','value'=>'cancel'))}}
{{Form::submit('save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'action','value'=>'save'))}}

//controller:

$action = Input::get('action', 'none');

if($action=='send'){
   //do send
}else if($action=='save'){
   //do save
}
```